# How to construct this 4-way X table leg arrangement?

Tags: wooden-furniture, design

I have googled a bit trying to find a similar project, but so far all I can find is [this page](http://lumberjocks.com/projects/96839).

[image]

Any suggestions on where to find guidance to build these legs?  Inspection of the photos hasn't helped.

The table I am building is a 34 inch diameter fir tree slab about 4 inches thick; it weighs about 40 kg (90 lbs).

Comment: I agree with the answer, but I'd probably also modify this to have 4 small square bits nested into the corners of the joint and screwed to the faces of the legs - not quite the same look, but a LOT stronger than just 1/2 of a 1/2 lap joint after slotting (1/4 lap joint?) - if not that, then stretchers (or a plywood disc/star "plate stretcher") below the crossover point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting design. A google search on the image leads to [The Four Leaf Clover Coffee Table](https://frivolousatlast.com/2014/03/23/the-four-leaf-clover-coffee-table/) which includes the image [image]

It looks like the "X"s use half-lap joints, then maybe matching slots in each X.

Comment: That helps, thanks!  Do you think after making the X's using half-laps that the X's are joined by cross-slotting?

Comment: That would be my guess. Any other kind of joinery would border on witchcraft IMO.